# Menelaus' Theorem & Concurrency

Tags: geometry

Given $\triangle ABC$, take $AD\perp BC$. Consider $DF\perp AC$, $DE\perp AB$, $DM\parallel AB$, $DN\parallel AC$.

[image]

I have to prove (through Menelaus' Theorem) that $MN$, $EF$ and $BC$ are concurrent.

Any hints?

Comment: How is concurrent defined in your text?

Comment: in my text concurrent is defined as having the same intersection point.

Comment: and i meant to put parallel sorry. and i dont have any clear accurate attempts as i dont have a similar problem to work off of

Comment: that is the exact question that i was given...so you know as much as i do...which is why i am asking for help

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Let us define $P$ as $BC\cap EF$: we just have to show that $MN$ goes through $P$.
The circle having diameter $AD$  and centre $O$ is the circumcircle of $AEDF$, hence $PD^2=PE\cdot PF$.
$ANDM$ is a parallelogram, hence the triangles $BND$ and $DMC$ are similar. If we set $H=PF\cap DM$ and prove that $CH\perp DM$ we are done, since we get that $P$ is a homotetic center for $BND$ and $DMC$. On the other hand $\widehat{HFD}=\widehat{EFD}=\widehat{EAD}=\widehat{EDB}$, so $DHFC$ is a cyclic quadrilateral and $CH\perp DM$ as wanted.

[image]

Comment: are you able to do it using Menelaus...

Comment: @eccaa: Yes I am, but I am not compelled to do it. The important identity $PD^2=PE\cdot PF$ is not really used in my proof: it is there for helping *you* to translate this proof in a proof through Menelaus' Theorem.

Comment: The Wikipedia page about Menelaus' Theorem clearly states that such result can be stated in terms of homothecies (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menelaus%27_theorem#A_proof_using_homothecies) that is exactly the way I followed here. On the other hand, my love for Mathematics also depends on the great freedom it grants in choosing the techniques for solving problems, so I tend to slightly dislike questions asking for *solve this, and solve it this way.*